# Is my proof of $-1=\eta_{\alpha\beta}U^\alpha U^\beta$ right?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, velocity

I tried to prove 
$$
-1=\eta_{\alpha\beta}U^\alpha U^\beta
$$
in my way, because I didn't understand from this 
$$
d\tau^2 =-\eta_{\alpha \beta} dx^\alpha dx^\beta
$$
we get 
$$
-1=\eta_{\alpha\beta}U^\alpha U^\beta
$$
which is from my text book.

So I made a proof, and I hope if anyone could say that its right or not:

$$
\tau^2 = -\eta_{\alpha\beta} x^\alpha x^\beta
$$
$$
2 \tau = -\eta_{\alpha\beta}(x^\alpha\dfrac{dx^\beta} {d\tau} +x^\beta \dfrac {dx^\alpha}{d\tau} )
$$
$$
2 \tau = -\eta_{\alpha\beta} (x^\alpha U^\beta +x^\beta U^\alpha )
$$
$$
-1=\eta_{\alpha\beta}\dfrac{ (x^\alpha U^\beta +x^\beta U^\alpha)}{2\tau} 
$$
$$
-1=\eta_{\alpha\beta}(\dfrac{1}{2}U^\alpha U^\beta +\dfrac{1}{2}U^\beta U^\alpha)
$$
$$
-1=\eta_{\alpha\beta}U^\alpha U^\beta
$$

Comment: This is not correct.  $U^\alpha\ne x^\alpha/\tau$ but instead $U^\alpha= dx^\alpha/d\tau$, much like $v_x=dx/dt$ and not just $x/t$

Comment: but isn't $$ x^1 / \tau $$ is like x^1 /t in three vector space @ZeroTheHero

Comment: right but that not the velocity.  The velocity is $dx^1/d\tau$, not $x^1\tau$.  Put another way, why not take $U^\alpha/\tau=A^\alpha$ instead?  By  the way your $\tau^2$ is also incorrect: the correct invariant is the spacetime *interval* $d\tau^2$.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Your proof would be correct for a body moving with **constant** 4-velocity, because then $U^\alpha = dx^\alpha /d\tau =x^\alpha /\tau$.

Comment: i'am convinced of what did you said but does $$ U^\alpha = \dfrac{ dx^\alpha}{d\tau} = \dfrac {x^\alpha}{\tau} $$ for a moving body with constant 4 velocity ?? and from your comment (the correct invariant is the spacetime interval $$d\tau^2$$) then how should i use it or write it    ( i think my questions are dump so thank you for time) @ZeroTheHero